# How to restore Fragment after unbindDrawables in onResume?

Tags: android, android-fragments

There is this piece of code all over the internet that people use in order to free up resources, especially bitmaps and prevent memory leaks:

```
public void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view !=null && view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view !=null && view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }

}
```

people say they call it in

```
onPause
```

or

```
onDestroy
```

or both.

No one mentions the fact that if you have opened a fragment, then open another one from it, and click back, the first fragment is left with an empty screen? Am I the only one experiencing this problem?

This happens only if I call this code from onPause.
If I call the code from onDestroy, I dont have this problem, because this method is called when the fragment is no longer in use, but then onDestroy doesnt get called every time and memory preservation isnt that efficient.

I tried to move all the stuff I usually do in onCreateView to onResume, but Im still unable to recreate the view hierarchy when I go back from the second fragment to the first one.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.container = container;


    getArgumentsAndAssignAccordingValuesToVariables();
    internetUtils = InternetConnectionUtils.getInstance(a);

            return getRootView(inflater, container);
} // End of onCreateView

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    assignLayoutsToJavaObjects(view);
    prepareUserInputEditText();
    initializeEntryLayout();
    setOnClickListeners();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 
    onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); // Just in case. Nothing good happenned
    onViewCreated(getRootView(inflater, container), savedInstanceState); // Just in case. Nothing good happenned
      activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    toggleKeyboard(true);
    setupActionbar();

}

private View getRootView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    if (rootView == null) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    }
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void assignLayoutsToJavaObjects(View rootView) {
    etUserInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etTextPageWithUserInput);
    ibGallery = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    rlTextPageWithUserInput = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rlTextPageWithUserInput);
    llEntryPhotos = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lEntryPhotos);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    hideKeyboard();

    stopRunningAsyncTasks();
    cleanMemoryFromBitmapsAndViews();
    rootView = null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    //cleanMemoryFromBitmapsAndViews();
    stopRunningAsyncTasks();
}

@Override
public void stopRunningAsyncTasks() {
    if (bitmapWorkAsync != null && activity.asyncTaskStatuses.contains(bitmapWorkAsync.getStatus())) {
        bitmapWorkAsync.cancel(true);
    }
}

private void prepareUserInputEditText() {
    if(etUserInput==null) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
        assignLayoutsToJavaObjects(rootView);
        rootView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Added this just in case, no positive change, though
        rootView.invalidate(); // Added this just in case, no positive change, though
    }
    etUserInput.requestFocus(); // Used to get a NPE here, so added the code above
    etUserInput.setCursorVisible(true);
    etUserInput.setHint("Hint");
}

private void initializeEntryLayout() {

    etUserInput.setText("Write here");
    etUserInput.setSelection(etUserInput.getText().length());

        llEntryPhotos.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < idsList.size(); i++) {
            LinearLayout photoView = createImageViewWithThumbnail(i);
            if (photoView != null) {
                llPhotos.addView(photoView);
            }

        }

} 

@Override
public void cleanMemoryFromBitmapsAndViews() {
    if (positionsAndBitmaps != null && positionsAndBitmaps.size() > 0) {
        for (Bitmap bitmap : positionsAndBitmaps.values()) {
            if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                bitmap.recycle();
                bitmap = null;
            }
        }
    }
    a.unbindDrawables(rlTextPageWithUserInput);
    a.unbindDrawables(llPhotos);
}
```

I even tried calling onCreateView() from onResume.

EDIT: I think I solved this by moving the destructive code from onPause/onDestroy to onDetach. I need more testing though. onDetach is called late enough when fragment is definitely not going to be used anymore, and I think its being called consistently enough.

Comment: Doesn't getRootView() return the previous rootView (with all its views removed) instead of re-inflating it? did you make sure to add rootView = null in your onPause, along with the other views you're removing?

Comment: Yes I do "rootView = null" in onPause

Comment: There's also no need to keep a reference to rootView. Use onViewCreated() method and bind the views there (you'll get the inflated view there). I suggest to move all your onResume code to there and see if that works.

Comment: I just tried it but got the same result. I dont think onViewCreated is called when I click the "back" button.

Comment: It does. onViewCreated() is called immediately after onCreateView() with the inflated view. Maybe post more of your Fragment

Comment: edited post with almost all of the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66725/discussion-between-lior-iluz-and-j-k).

Comment: There is no need to unbind all your `Drawable`s, especially not in `onPause()` (which is completely the wrong place for it), unless you are holding a static reference to them. See the [Android Developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) on avoiding memory leaks for some context on this. Also, since ICS (or possibly Honeycomb), `Drawable`s hold only a weak reference to their `Callback`s, so unbinding is no longer strictly necessary post-ICS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved the unbindDrawables code to

```
onDetach()
```

This way it almost always gets called and most importantly it gets called at a time where the fragment is no longer in use, so we dont have the problem with trying to restore and redraw the fragment's views